# Unnamed faces in my oven

Tags: macos, photos.app

[image: Unnamed faces in oven]
[image: Unnamed faces in oven 2]

Iphoto is putting a high number of unnamed faces in pictures of food in my oven. It's not happening in other pictures, at least I can't see another pattern.

Why is this happening and how can I avoid this?

Comment: now that is a new one! the pizza looks delicious :)

Comment: actually this kind of imagery should be forbidden!

Comment: that would be so funny if it would have been actually able to identify a few of your oven parts with actual names/people....

Comment: You monster!!!!

Comment: If only we could get iPhoto to award holiday hats to the unnamed masses, then this would be the perfect question for the hour.

Comment: iPhoto once identified a bowling ball as my grandfather.

Comment: These are ninjas.

Comment: Congratulations on purchasing your Holy Fire Oven with Christ-Crust™ technology to put Jesus' face on all your oven baked goods for your graven image needs.  If you are experiencing multiple faces of Our Savior, we recommending adding less holy water to your recipes.  If the faces are not recognizable or are of low quality, you may need to clean or replace your spirit filter.  To avoid your food melting your face off, be sure your measuring cups and bakeware are made of humble materials such as wood, iron, glass and stone.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

According to this [Apple Support Document](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201891), images with blurry, badly lit, or very small faces may detect faces where they do not exist. iPhoto can sometimes detect the back of a person's head as a face.

I notice that you've taken the photo through the oven's window, which has a semi-pixelated insulating reflective coating on the inside. Perhaps this kind of pattern, combined with the delicious foods behind them, makes iPhoto think faces are in the image when they aren't.

This [Apple Discussions thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4721352) discusses the inability to turn off face detection in iPhoto, but talks about being able to turn it off in [Aperture](https://www.apple.com/aperture/).

Unfortunately, other than marking each of these phantom faces and deleting their entries, or taking the photos with the oven door open, I think you'll have no luck fixing the problem.

I have to admit I'm chuckling at these two images you've provided.

Comment: +1 for "iPhoto can sometimes detect the back of a person's head as a face." Made me giggle.

Comment: Professor Quirrell!

Answer (score 38):

iPhoto is not as wrong as one might think.

Examining the first picture carefully i indeed found some faces:

Dramatically increasing contrast and saturation of some channels and lowering brightness of the residual channel the villains come to light:

[image: goblins]

While the two inside the oven are just interested in the food, the other two create the impression that they are up to no good outside the oven.

So get a new stove because your current one seems to be irretrievably lost to the creatures. And don't always mistrust iPhoto presenting dubious results.

;-)

Comment: I was going to down vote this as it is not an answer.. but I just can't bring myself to do it because it is so funny..:-)

Comment: iPhoto was obviously trained with the same pareidolia as the human brain to see faces in random objects.

Comment: I was going to suggest tagging these phantoms in the oven shots so that you can find out where else they are lurking in the darkness - waiting for Apple's eager algorithms to suss them out.

Comment: Thank you for posting this!  Now, the iTunes store will be flooded with hundreds of "Ghost Detector" apps because the iPhone can can detect the paranormal!

Comment: @RLH, but yum yum goblins are perfectly natural creatures.